# Which is the most ancient scripture?

Tags: scripture, vedas

It is often said RigVeda is most ancient. And then the other 3 Vedas. And after them the rest Puraanas, Smriti et cetera come.

But is this true. Is there really something to be affiliated to scriptures that this scripture is most ancient, and this is a latter scripture.

Comment: Related: [Which is the oldest known Hindu text in recorded history?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11658/277)

Comment: Yeah vedas are the oldest as all scriptures(Upanishads,puranas,agamas,itihasa,smritis mention vedas and accept them as authority and even according to scholars they are the oldest

Comment: Btw you can ask question that how do we know that Rig veda is the oldest of the vedas.

Comment: @Pandya O god! I tried to search the site a lot to see if my question is not duplicate. But it is. Even I was thinking, how can somebody else not ask this question earlier than me. Probably I was trying to search with word "ancient". Haha. ;D